# My MVVM is not load data first time kotlin when I open the app

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My data is not loaded the first time I opened my application. It need refresh to load the data. But I need to load data every time when My application opened

I called this viewmodel from here

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    liveDataModel= ViewModelProvider(this)[ClientPostViewModel::class.java]
    _binding=FragmentClientJobPostBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)
    return binding.root
}
```

My ViewModel code

```
  class ClientPostViewModel: ViewModel() {
private  var getData=MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ClientPostDataModel>>()
fun getLiveData():MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ClientPostDataModel>>{
    PostRepo.setJobPost()
  
    return PostRepo.getJobPost() as MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ClientPostDataModel>>
}
```

}

This is my repository code

```
 object PostRepo {
    private val jobPostList= mutableSetOf<ClientPostDataModel>()
    fun getJobPost():LiveData<ArrayList<ClientPostDataModel>> {
        setJobPost()
        val mutableList=MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ClientPostDataModel>>()
        mutableList.value= ArrayList(jobPostList)
        return mutableList
    }
    fun setJobPost(){
       val auth=Firebase.auth
       val db=Firebase.firestore.collection("collectionName")
       val query=db.whereEqualTo("filedname",auth.uid.toString())
       query.get().addOnSuccessListener {
           for (doc in it.documents){
              val clientjobpostdatamodel= doc.toObject(ClientPostDataModel::class.java)
               if (clientjobpostdatamodel != null) {
                   jobPostList.add(clientjobpostdatamodel)
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the getLiveData() method from?

Comment: Because your `LiveData` / `MutableLiveData` should never expose mutable properties or mutable data collections. So `ArrayList` should be `List`, and `mutableSetOf` should be `setOf`.